# Home Page url in sitemap

Tags: magento2.2.4, php-7.2

How to find out the home page url in sitemap generated url....

I have created site map in magento2.2.4.

I want to customize homepage url.But that url does not display in sitemap generated url.

How to find out homepage url in the sitemap

Comment: What you want  to do ? add Homepage sitemap.xml?

Comment: I need to get home page url .....

Comment: `get home page url ` ? donot understand the comment?

Comment: In sitemap.xml , contains list of category,Product,Cms page url ...i want to get one of the cms page url name like  if (strpos($xml, "home") == true) {}

Comment: In magento 2.2.2, one of the cms page url contains home key word....But magento2.2.4 ,  i can't see the home page url.

Comment: From 2.2.4 Magento exclude  the homepage url sitemap url .take a look on Commit https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6ea1c43040a0364ee2483837256077511dc1301a#diff-276e3b42b22e6981329d89d398bd86dd

Comment: so in magento2.2.4 , sitemap.xml does not contain home_page and no_route,no_cookies url?

Comment: Yes, it `home_page` 's this cms page use at home page then it does not show at sitemap.xml